# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'newValue' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I'm pretty sure that I am inserting the correct data.  I have drop all Indexes, Triggers, Constraint to make sure nothing is intervening my insert.

Here's the catch: the field that I'm trying to insert to previously has a datatype of int but changed to nvarchar(100) later.  Does anybody know where should I look into?

This is the table structure

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable.Values](
    [myTableId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [myTableCode] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [value] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UpdateById] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_myTable.Values] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [myTableCode] ASC,
    [Code] ASC,
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, `ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]`
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and this is the script for insert

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[myTable.Values] (
        [myTableId]
        ,[myTableCode]
        ,[Code]
        ,[value]
        ,[UpdateById]
        ,[UpdateDate]
        )
    VALUES (
        581
        ,'myParentTableCODE'
        ,'myTableNewCode'
        ,'myTableNewCode'
        ,5197
        ,getdate()
        )
```

Comment: You may want to post your schema and code. Please elaborate what `*failed*` means exactly. Tag your question with an appropriate RDBMS.

Comment: Please edit your post and paste your code there in a proper format. Based on the code it seems to be `SQL Server`. If so add the tag while your adding your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for looking into this, I have found out one of our View is using "WITH SCHEMABINDING" clause.  And that view is Casting the field "Code" as int.  Here is the view.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vSomeView] WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT
id,
CAST(Code AS INT) AS [Code],
myTableCode
FROM dbo.[myTable.Values]
WHERE myTableCode LIKE '%ABC'
AND ISNUMERIC(Code) = 1
```

Comment: Part of the problem is related to the issue [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) where SQL Server *should* (logically) process the `WHERE` clause before the `SELECT` clause and therefore not raise an error. However, you would also need a better guard clause because `ISNUMERIC` doesn't answer the question people thinks it does.

Comment: You are right, I have tested the code without the ISNUMERIC but WITH SCHEMABINDING in it and it passed.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

it seems yourinsertion code is not complete, you should to add another field and assign value to it,the field is `IsDefaultObsolete`, then try this code for insert :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[myTable.Values] (
    [myTableId]
    ,[myTableCode]
    ,[Code]
    ,[value]
    ,[IsDefaultObsolete]
    ,[UpdateById]
    ,[UpdateDate]
    )
VALUES (
    581
    ,'myParentTableCODE'
    ,'myTableNewCode'
    ,'myTableNewCode'
    0,--THIS MAY BE 0 OR 1 DEPENDING YOU
    ,5197
    ,getdate()
    )
```

Comment: Sorry that field is not supposed to be there.